# problems downloading zip with ngnix

Tags: nginx

I installed ngnix last night with no hassle. It is serving html files with no problem but when I add a zip file and try to download it the webbrowser starts downloading (it doesn't go further than 0%) and after 5 or 6 secs it reports a "error downloading file". I have the sendifle option set to on and have a mime-type file in the same directory that has a line with "application/zi zip" to let the browser know what to do with the zip file. Could anybody guess what is hapenning? I'm a bit frustrated.

If I rename the .zip file to for example .cfg it can be downloaded with no problem. The only problem is with .zip extensions :/. It is really odd.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post nginx's config file here?

Comment: I will as soon as I get home thanks.